# Event fired multiple times with window.addEventListener in Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component, window

I have this html code inside my Vue component

```
<div id="stats" class="" @click="clickOutside()">
          <ArticleStats
            :article="article"
            class="tw-mt-5 tw-hidden md:tw-flex"
            
          />
          <div
            @click="$router.push('/article/' + article.content_content_id)"
            class="
              tw-mt-5 tw-block tw-text-center tw-text-sm
              md:tw-text-base
              tw-cursor-pointer
              tw-text-white
              tw-p-2
              tw-rounded-2xl
              tw-w-full
              tw-bg-red-400
              hover:tw-bg-red-600 hover:tw-text-white
            "
          >
            Leer más
          </div>
        </div>
```

And that method clickOutside() is this:

```
clickOutside() {
      console.log('hola')
      window.addEventListener("mouseup", (e) => {
        console.log(e);
        const clickedE1 = e.target;

        if (this.$el.contains(clickedE1)) {
          console.log("inside");
        } else {
          console.log("outside");
        }
      });
    },
```

But when I click on that div the event is fired multiple times, this is the response in the console with a single click:

[image]

Anyone maybe know how to fix it or why this is happening?

Comment: It's a mistake to not remove a listener when you don't need it. I see no reason to add a listener on every click, it could be added once

Comment: @EstusFlask Yes, you're right, I put the even listener in the mounted hook. However, it takes the click of the whole component, not the little piece that I need to listen to. The piece of code that I put here is just the part I need to listen but it is wrapped in a major component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I finally did was create an event listener on the created hook, remove it on the destroyed hook, and add a method that detects the target, this way:

```
created() {
    window.addEventListener("mouseup", this.onMouseUp);
  },
  destroyed() {
    window.removeEventListener("mouseup", this.onMouseUp);
  },
methods: {
    onMouseUp(e) {
      const clickedE1 = e.target;
      if (this.$el.contains(clickedE1)) {
        console.log("inside");
      } else {
        console.log("outside");
      }
    },
  },
```

And that was all, it finally worked the way I wanted. Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

This is fired by the element and its children, so you should add the `self` modifier to prevent that behavior :

```html
<div id="stats" class="" @click.self="clickOutside()">
```

For more details check this https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#event-modifiers